# ansible delegate_to doesn't use inventory host?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I'm attempting to use ansible synchronize to copy files between two remotes.

My playbook looks like:

```
- hosts: newserver
  tasks:
    - name: Copy images from old to new
      synchronize:
        src: /var/www/production/
        dest: /var/www/production/
      delegate_to: oldserver
```

Where `newserver` and `oldserver` are defined in my inventory file. If I replace `oldserver` with the full hostname the delegate_to works. Otherwise it complains about unreachable. `oldserver` works fine in other places in other playbooks.

Doesn't delegate_to use the inventory?

The error I get is:

```
TASK [Copy images from old to new] *************************************************
fatal: [thr.cs.unc.edu]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ", "unreachable": true}
```

`newserver` is reachable from `oldserver`. As I said above, if I change `oldserver` to `gbserver3.cs.unc.edu` in the delegate_to it works.

My hosts file looks like this:

```
[newserver]
thr.cs.unc.edu
[oldserver]
gbserver3.cs.unc.edu
```

Comment: Update the question with the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have updated the question above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `newserver` and `oldserver` aren't the names of the hosts but names of the groups. It's not possible *delegate_to* a group. See [Inventory basics: formats, hosts, and groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-basics-formats-hosts-and-groups)

```
[newserver]
thr.cs.unc.edu
[oldserver]
gbserver3.cs.unc.edu
```

Fix the inventory. For example

```
newserver ansible_host=thr.cs.unc.edu
oldserver ansible_host=gbserver3.cs.unc.edu
```

Answer (score 6):

`delegate_to` expects an inventory **host name**.

From your inventory, `oldserver` is a **group name** that can potentially hold several host names.

A quick and dirty fix if you are sure that your group will always contain a single host is to use the first one in the list inside the group. So in this case you could `delegate_to: "{{ groups['oldserver'][0] }}"`